# How to get variable attribute values?

Tags: c#, attributes

My goal is to get class properties attribute and it's values.

For example, if I have an attribute 'Bindable' to check if property is bindable:

```
public class Bindable : Attribute
{
    public bool IsBindable { get; set; }
}
```

And I have a Person class:

```
public class Person
{
    [Bindable(IsBindable = true)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Bindable(IsBindable = false)]
    public string LastName { get; set; } 
}
```

How can I get FirstName's and LastName's 'Bindable' attribute values?

```
    public void Bind()
    {
        Person p = new Person();

        if (FirstName property is Bindable)
            p.FirstName = "";
        if (LastName property is Bindable)
            p.LastName = "";
    }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Instances* don't have separate attributes - you have to ask the *type* for its members (e.g. with [`Type.GetProperties`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6kec8wwk.aspx)), and ask those members for their attributes (e.g. [`PropertyInfo.GetCustomAttributes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dzdb2077.aspx)).

EDIT: As per comments, there's a [tutorial on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288454.aspx) about attributes.

Comment: There's a nice [Attributes Tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288454.aspx) that covers this on MSDN.

Comment: @JonSkeet I have one variable called `string key` and in that value is `profile_image`, so can I get the value of the `key` and set it as attribute dynamically?

Comment: beacuse my method need a value like `attribute=value`

Comment: @PrashantPimpale: It's not really clear what you're trying to do, I'm afraid. It's probably worth asking in a new question.

Comment: @JonSkeet Here is a described question https://stackoverflow.com/q/53046664/7124761

Answer (score 3):

You can try by this way:

```
     public class Bindable : Attribute
        {
            public bool IsBindable { get; set; }
        }

        public class Person
        {
            [Bindable(IsBindable = true)]
            public string FirstName { get; set; }

            [Bindable(IsBindable = false)]
            public string LastName { get; set; }
        }

        public class Test
        {
            public void Bind()
            {
                Person p = new Person();

                foreach (PropertyInfo property in p.GetType().GetProperties())
                {

                   try
                   {
                       Bindable _Attribute = (Bindable)property.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(Bindable), false).First();

                       if (_Attribute.IsBindable)
                       {
                            //TODO
                       }
                    }
                    catch (Exception) { }
                }
            }
        }
```