# Get the value of variable and assign as attribute in C#

Tags: c#

There is one API method which looks like:

```
Task<Response> UpdateImage([AliasAs("banner_image")] StreamPart banner_image=null,[AliasAs("background_image")] StreamPart background_image =null);
```

But at a time only one image will be there from Frond-End

For ex. I got an image for `banner_image` then

```
APIHelper.UpdateImage(banner_image: image)
```

I getting the attribute information from one variable like,

```
string key = "banner_image";
```

So the question is how I can get the value of `key` and pass it like,

```
APIHelper.UpdateImage(`dynamic_key_extracted_from_key_variable_value`: image)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot. That is a language/compiler feature, not available at runtime.

(And for a reason, how should it react when you suddenly pass "xzy"? Have a time-travelling compiler error that reaches you when you compiled it 2 weeks ago?)

Your easiest way around it might be:

```
StreamPart banner_image = null;
StreamPart background_image = null;

if(key == "banner_image")
{
    banner_image = value;
}

if(key == "background_image")
{
    background_image = value;
}

UpdateImage(banner_image, background_image);
```

Comment: Have used switch case which manipulates the value on the basis of key but thinking is it possible or not with above approach